# Check if property has been set in phing

Tags: phing

How to check if property `${foo}` has been set?

Bonus question: how to *escape* `$` sign in `<echo>` so I could output `${foo}` string (not the `foo` variable substitution)?

PS: tried to google and read documentation, but couldn't find the answers. It's likely I'm missing something

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to place an `isset` element inside the `if` element.

```
<if>
    <isset property="foo" />
```

The manual is available [here](https://www.phing.info/docs/guide/trunk/conditions.html).

Comment: or add if="variable" as attribute of the tag to run it only if the variable is set. From experience, better to avoid complex conditional statements for maintenance reasons

Comment: The problem with both answers here is that they don't let you check if anything has been assigned to the respective properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to fail the build if a property is defined or not, check out the `fail` task:

http://www.phing.info/docs/guide/stable/FailTask.html